# how to adjust heights of 2 buttons beside each others with different contents

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 column layout like below. the problem is when I set the buttons height to wrap contents and one of buttons contents is wrapped to next line. I want to know is it possible to set both buttons with same height?

[image]

this is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnPersonalInfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFC40D"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/person"
                android:onClick="clickHandler"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/personal_info"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLawyerInfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#EE1111"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/lawyer"
                android:onClick="clickHandler"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/lawyer_info"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSharesInfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#2976DE"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/shares"
                android:onClick="clickHandler"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/buy_sell"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFinancialInfo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#902293"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/wallet"
                android:onClick="clickHandler"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/financial_info"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNews"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#0D9A0E"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/news"
                android:onClick="clickHandler"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/news"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnMessages"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#CA5A35"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/messages"
                android:onClick="clickHandler"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/messages"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSync"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/pink"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/sync"
                android:onClick="clickHandler"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/update"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnExit"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#AF274D"
                android:drawableTop="@drawable/quit"
                android:onClick="clickHandler"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:text="@string/exit"
                android:textColor="@color/button_text" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set all the `Button`s' heights to `match_parent`, but keep the `LinearLayout`s' heights as `wrap_content`.

That should make the `Button`s expand vertically to fill the `LinearLayout`s, but the `LinearLayout`s themselves will not grow unless they need to.